# Can I change my departure date from the UK and the accommodation after being granted a Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I am about to apply for a Visitor visa, however I am still unsure about the departure date because I feel that two weeks are not really enough. Would it be possible for me to change the departure date once I got the visa, for example from the 15th to 27th? If I changed it before the arrival, would they then question me because the ticket date differed from the application? Or is it fine to change it afterwards, but would they question me during the new departure date when I'm about to go home?

The same thing goes for my accommodation. I had made some bookings, but if I changed some of them, for example decided to stay at a friend's house for three days or change hotels, after the visa was granted, would this be allowed?

Comment: No problems with any of the things you wrote about.  The travel dates on an application are indicative only.

Comment: Changing your itinerary from two weeks to three weeks is probably fine. Changing it to five months is not; you should expect such a change to reflect negatively on future visa applications.

Comment: Thank you, @GayotFow and MichaelHampton. But would they notice such changes? For example when I first arrived in the UK and show that the return date on my ticket is not the same as the one in the application. Or should I change the flight ticket during my stay instead? And would they realise that it's different?

Comment: They look for large variances the NEXT time you apply. Two weeks is not a big deal, but if you are unsure then put down the 27th as your departure date!  Honestly, for what you have described, it's not a big deal.  Worry about something else.